# Many Panel in scrolledPanel wxpython

Tags: python, wxwidgets

My problem is this :

I have created a scrolledPanel in a Frame. In this scrolledPanel I have a BoxSizer which contains several panels. When I add to many panels in BoxSizer, panels are stacked in the end of BoxSizer.

I am completely stuck with this problem and still have no clue as to how to fix it.

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial", size=(200,500))

    # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

    # --------------------
    # Scrolled panel stuff
    self.scrolled_panel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.panel, -1,
                             style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, name="panel1")
    self.scrolled_panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
    self.scrolled_panel.SetupScrolling()

    words = range(0,2000)
    self.spSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.spSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.spSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for word in words:
        text = wx.TextCtrl(self.scrolled_panel, value=str(word))
        self.spSizer.Add(text)

    self.scrolled_panel.SetSizer(self.spSizer)
    self.scrolled_panel.Layout()
    self.scrolled_panel.SetupScrolling()
    # --------------------

    btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Add Widget")
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAdd)

    panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    panelSizer.AddSpacer(50)
    panelSizer.Add(self.scrolled_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    panelSizer.Add(btn)
    self.panel.SetSizer(panelSizer)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onAdd(self, event):
    """"""
    print "in onAdd"
    new_text = wx.TextCtrl(self.scrolled_panel, value="New Text")
    self.spSizer.Add(new_text)
    self.scrolled_panel.Layout()
    self.scrolled_panel.SetupScrolling()

 # Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I put a code sample that shows the problem

Comment: It can be useful to add some code. Firstly, see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795726/scrolledpanel-inside-panel-not-sizing. Also, see http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.scrolledpanel.html.

Comment: I put the code. I've watched the doc